# How to check if record is exist in python sqlite3 and raise error in tkinter?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

Hi I'am new in sql and I'm trying to make a tkinter application with sqlite3 backend for database. I want to insert a data to the sqlite database and if the record is exists it raise an error in tkinter app.

Comment: Actually exception will be raised when you try to insert duplicate record into table if it has defined unique key constraint.  So just use `try/except` block to perform the insertion and show error in the except block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a SQL query to see if the record already exists.

If it does, display a messagebox with the error message.

checking the presence of a record can be done by

```sql
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE some_column="some_value");
```

then in your code, you can do

```py
import tkinter.messagesbox as msgb
if exists:  # exists value comes from executing the query above
    msgb.showerror('Record already exists', 'Looks like the record alreadye xists')
else:
    # continue to inset the record
    pass
```

Comment: @P S Solanki i got error " exists" is not declared.

Comment: the `exists` variable is supposed to come from the output of the SQL query I posted above. 

So you need to execute the query using the cursor, get the output, assign `True` or `False` accordingly to variable `exists` and then use that in the if condition.